# uploading image to google cloud storage from app (IOS or android)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using react native, and want to upload image to gcp storage 
I am not using any app engine.
According to gcp documentation for node

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = Storage({
  projectId: 'id',
  keyFilename: 'private-key'
});

const bucketName = 'buckt';

// Uploads a local file to the bucket
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .upload('filename')
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

To use this code in client, I need to pass private key which I don't want to do

According to this blog post https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556 , there is a get_serving_url() function in google app engine.

I reckon for Google Push notifications, google provides each client token so that client directly communicates with server

Is there any way where I can upload image directly from client?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firabase Cloud Storage service. This service provides securely upload to GCP Storage from the client based on Firebase Auth credential. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/